# Validating CSV format

Tags: c

I am writing a program to validate a CSV file. The limitations on the format are:

- A line cannot end with a comma, it must end with a digit;
- A line cannot start with a comma, it must be a digit;
- A line can be blank;
- Only single digits are allowed as numbers (i.e. no numbers below 0 or greater than 9);
- Two commas cannot be next to each other, they must be separated by a digit.

EDIT:

I have made some changes to the code based on the feedback. Can someone please explain what the while loop is actually doing? And why isn't the switch working? I am now getting 1's for all input. Can I use isdigit in the switch?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{

int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF )
    {      
        switch(c)
    {
        case'0':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'1':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'2':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'3':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'4':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'5':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'6':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'7':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'8':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'9':
            printf("1");
            break;
        case',' :
            printf("1");
            break;
        case'\n' :
            printf("1");
            break;
        default :
            printf("0");
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is some code missing? This will never get to the switch. Also, is valid() recursive on purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define bool int
#define false 0
#define true !false

// Rule:(SPACE* | [0-9](,[0-9])*)CR
bool isValid(char *str){
    if(*str == '\n')
        return true;
    if(*str == ' '){
        while(*++str == ' ');
        if(*str == '\n')
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    if(isdigit(*str++)){
        do{
            if(*str == '\n')
                return true;
        }while(*str++ == ',' && isdigit(*str++));
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

#define BUFF_SIZE 128

int main(void){
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("\nEnd with comma:\n");
    printf(isValid("1,2,3,\n") ? "OK" : "NG");
    printf("\nStart with comma:\n");
    printf(isValid(",1,2,3\n") ? "OK" : "NG");
    printf("\nCR only:\n");
    printf(isValid("\n") ? "OK" : "NG");
    printf("\nSPACE and CR only:\n");
    printf(isValid("     \n") ? "OK" : "NG");
    printf("\nBelow zero:\n");
    printf(isValid("-1\n") ? "OK" : "NG");
    printf("\nGreater than nine:\n");
    printf(isValid("10\n") ? "OK" : "NG");
    printf("\nInclude two comma:\n");
    printf(isValid("3,4,,5\n") ? "OK" : "NG");
    printf("\nNormal pattern I:\n");
    printf(isValid("9\n") ? "OK" : "NG");
    printf("\nNormal pattern II:\n");
    printf(isValid("3,4,5\n") ? "OK" : "NG");
#else
    char line[BUFF_SIZE];
redo:
    fgets(line, BUFF_SIZE, stdin);
    if(NULL==strchr(line, '\n')){
        fprintf(stderr,"You have exceeded the number of characters that can be entered.\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        goto redo;
    }
    if(isValid(line))
        printf("OK\n");
    else
        printf("NG\n");
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that, I really appreciate it. Is there any way that it can be done with getchar though? I have been told by my uni teacher that this should be able to be done with getchar and be a small program.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    int ch;
    while(EOF!=(ch=getchar())){
        if(ch == ' '){
            while(' '==(ch=getchar()));
            goto CR;
        }
        if(isdigit(ch)){
            while(','==(ch=getchar()))
                if(isdigit(getchar()))
                    continue;
                else
                    goto NG;
            goto CR;
        }
CR:     if(ch != '\n')
            goto NG;
    }
    printf("OK");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
NG:
    printf("NG");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

#if 0
    while(EOF!=(ch=getchar())){
        if(ch == ' '){
            while(' '==(ch=getchar()));
        } else if(isdigit(ch)){
            while(','==(ch=getchar()))
                if(!isdigit(getchar()))
                    break;//ch==','
        }
        if(ch != '\n')
            goto NG;
    }
#endif
```

Comment: How to draw a diagram was hard.;-)

Comment: +627287282828 for the drawing & the help!

Comment: This program isn't  match to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code never reach the switch statement.

In short the recursion goes:

```
int valid() /* This is the function definition. */
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if(!valid(c)) {  /* While not EOF you keep calling valid() 
                            You also pass 'c' - which you can't get
                            as your function _definition_ does not have 
                            any arguments. */
           return 0;     /* You never get here as valid() always, when EOF, 
                            return 1 */
        }
    }
    return 1; /* When EOF you never go _inside_ the while loop, 
                 you return 1, 
                 and back track of stack begins. */

    switch(c) { ... /* You never get here. */
}
```

Resulting in `valid()` always returning `1`.

Also note:

```
int valid();        /* This _declaration_ has no arguments thus indicating the 
                       _definition_ of the function can have any number of 
                       arguments. */

int valid(void);    /* This would explicitly say that the _definition_ does not
                       take any arguments. */

int valid(int);
int valid(int foo); /* These would explicitly say the _definition takes
                       one int, and one int only. */
```

---

As an example of calls:

```
file.csv:
  0,2
  1,2
```

Call stack steps:

```
Down            Up
01 main()       20 valid() return 1 so puts("1")
02 valid()      19 ... return 1
03 valid('0')   18 ... return 1
04 valid(',')   17 ... return 1
05 valid('2')   16 ... return 1
06 valid('\n')  15 ... return 1
07 valid('1')   14 Step  8 returns 1, so return 1
08 valid(',')   13 Step  9 returns 1, so return 1
09 valid('2')   12 Step 10 returns 1, so return 1
10 Now at EOF,  11 Never inside while as EOF, return 1.
 v              ^  Start popping calls from stack.
 |              |
 +--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what logic exactly your program is following but there is a **strange looking recursion** here

```
int valid()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) !=EOF) {
        if (!valid(c)) {
```

And you are passing an `int` to `valid()` which should *ideally* not accept anything.

I think this code goes into an **infinite spin**

Even if you remove that recursive call, you bump into a plain `return 1`. I think you need to take that off as well

Answer (score 0):

look up isdigit().  That will replace a big chunk of your switch statement, and make this shorter so it can be more easily scanned.

Also, you might want to read the input a line at a time (gets() / fgets()) instead of a character at a time, then make a test for a single line.

Answer (score 0):

rewrite version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define bool int
#define false 0
#define true !false

// Rule:(SPACE* | [0-9](,[0-9])*)CR
bool isValid(FILE *fp){
    int ch;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp))){
        if(ch == '\n')
            continue;
        if(ch == ' '){
            while((ch=fgetc(fp)) == ' ');
            if(ch == '\n')
                continue;
            else
                return false;
        }
        if(isdigit(ch)){
            do{
                if((ch=fgetc(fp)) == '\n')
                    goto cont; //continue
            }while(ch == ',' && isdigit(fgetc(fp)));
            return false;
        }
        return false;
        cont:;
    }
    return true;
}

int main(void){
    FILE *file;
#ifdef DEBUG
    file = fopen("testdata.csv","r");
#else
    file = stdin;
#endif
    if(isValid(file))
        printf("OK");
    else
        printf("NG");
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef enum STATUS {
    START,SPC,NUM,COMMA,CR
} Status;

int main(void){
    int ch;
    Status pre_stat, stat;
    pre_stat=stat=START;

    while(EOF!=(ch=getchar())){
        switch(ch){
        case '\n':
            stat = CR;
            if(pre_stat == START || pre_stat == SPC || pre_stat == NUM){
                //pre_stat = stat;
                pre_stat = START;//line end move to line start, reset status
            } else
                goto NG;
            break;
        case ' ':
            stat = SPC;
            if(pre_stat == START || pre_stat == SPC){
                pre_stat = stat;
            } else
                goto NG;
            break;
        case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
        case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
            stat = NUM;
            if(pre_stat == START || pre_stat == COMMA){
                pre_stat = stat;
            } else
                goto NG;
            break;
        case ',':
            stat = COMMA;
            if(pre_stat == NUM){
                pre_stat = stat;
            } else
                goto NG;
            break;
        default:
            goto NG;
        }
    }
    printf("OK");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
NG:
    printf("NG");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```